# pandas: how do I select first row in each GROUP BY group?

Tags: python, pandas

Basically the same as [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) only in pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
                'B' : ['3', '1', '2', '4','2', '4', '1', '3'],
                    })
```

Sorting looks promising:

```
df.sort('B')

     A  B
1  foo  1
6  bar  1
2  foo  2
4  bar  2
0  foo  3
7  bar  3
3  foo  4
5  bar  4
```

But then first won't give the desired result... 
    df.groupby('A').first()

```
     B
A     
bar  2
foo  3
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Generally if you want your data sorted in a groupby but it's not one of the columns which are going to be grouped on then it's better to [`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort) the df prior to performing `groupby`:

```
In [5]:
df.sort_values('B').groupby('A').first()

Out[5]:
     B
A     
bar  1
foo  1
```

Comment: hey, I'm preferring @JohnE's method as it's cleaner and more SQL-like. Maybe in pandas you can rely on sorting to be stable after grouping by another column (timsort?) but it's not as obvious as the `rank` syntax

Comment: @ihadanny. I totally agree, poor idea on pandas side.

Comment: I know this is old, but as of November 2022 [`first`'s behaviour](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8427) is does not do what the OP asked. For most cases, I think users might want to use `nth(0)`. Added a [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58224848/9786776) a while back explaining the difference.

Answer (score 16):

Here's an alternative approach using `groupby().rank()`:

```
df[ df.groupby('A')['B'].rank() == 1 ]

     A  B
1  foo  1
6  bar  1
```

This gives you the same answer as @EdChum's for the OP's sample dataframe, but could give a different answer if you have any ties during the sort, for example, with data like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'], 
                   'B': ['2', '1', '1', '1'] })
```

In this case you have some options using the optional `method` argument, depending on how you wish to handle sorting ties:

```
df[ df.groupby('A')['B'].rank(method='average') == 1 ]   # the default
df[ df.groupby('A')['B'].rank(method='min')     == 1 ]
df[ df.groupby('A')['B'].rank(method='first')   == 1 ]   # doesn't work, not sure why
```

Comment: The problem is that ``df.sort('B')`` returns a sorted *copy* of df, it does not change df itself. If you want to change df, you need to do one of the following: ``df = df.sort_values('B')`` or ``df.sort_values(inplace=True)``. (pandas now uses ``sort_values`` instead of ``sort``.)

Answer (score 14):

The [pandas groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) function could be used for what you want, but it's really meant for aggregation. This is a simple 'take the first' operation.

What you actually want is the [pandas drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) function, which by default will return the first row. What you usually would consider the groupby key, you should pass as the subset= variable

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='A')
```

Should do what you want.

Also, `df.sort('A')` does not sort the DataFrame df, it returns a copy which is sorted. If you want to sort it, you have to add the `inplace=True` parameter.

```
df.sort('A', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @firelynx, but what I was really looking for is `df.sort('B').groupby('A').first()`

Answer (score 12):

[EdChum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486417/pandas-how-do-i-select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/30486565#30486565) may not always work as intended. Instead of `first()` use `nth(0)`.

The method `first()` is affected by [this bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8427) that has gone unsolved for some years now. Instead of the expected behaviour, `first()` returns the first element **that is not missing** in each column within each group i.e. it ignores NaN values. For example, say you had a third column with some missing values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
                   'B' : ['1', '2','2', '4', '1'],
                   'C' : [np.nan, 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']})

    A   B   C
0   foo 1   NaN
2   foo 2   X
3   bar 2   Y
4   bar 4   Y
5   bar 1   Y
```

Using `first()` here (after sorting, just like EdChum correctly assessed in their answer) will skip over the missing values (note how it is mixing up values from different rows):

```
df.sort_values('B').groupby('A').first()

    B   C
A       
bar 1   Y
foo 1   X
```

The correct way to get the full row, including missing values, is to use `nth(0)`, which performs the expected operation:

```
df.sort_values('B').groupby('A').nth(0)

    B   C
A       
bar 1   Y
foo 1   NaN
```

For completeness, this bug also affects `last()`, its correct substitute being `nth(-1)`.

Posting this in an answer since it's too long for a comment. Not sure this is within the scope of the question but I think it's relevant to many people looking for this answer (like myself before writing this) and is extremely easy to miss.

Comment: This answer is probably the most important within this thread as of early 2020. The longstanding bug with pandas aggregation is so silent that it appears to work, until you inspect your output real carefully - especially with large dataset. Glad that nth() provides a quick way out

Answer (score 5):

Use a sort method and then keep the first value using [`.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with its `keep` argument set to `'first'` (default). This approach has the benefit that it keeps your index.

Example:

```
df.sort_values('B', ascending=True) \
  .drop_duplicates('A', keep='first')
```

Output:

```
    A   B
1   foo 1
6   bar 1
```

You don’t need a `GroupBy` in this case because there is no need to run a calculation on each group (see: [split-apply-combine pattern](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)).

Comment: Note - You can keep each first unique combination by feeding `.sort_values()` and `.drop_duplicates()` a list of column names.

Comment: The default value for the `keep` argument in `.drop_duplicates()` is "first". Setting it explicitly is optional but can improve readability in contexts like these.