# Pandas Group by a Column and take the non null values in different rows for each column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandasql

I have an interesting question for which I am not getting any built-in solution in Pandas.

I have data like:

```
A B    C    D    E     F
1 null null Red  null  12
1 89   76   Red  null  null
1 null null null null  12
```

I am trying to get an output like:

```
1 89 76 Red null 12
```

Now, these data are messages coming at different times. Many messages belong to a single transaction.

So, suppose A is the identifier of the transaction. Some messages with the same identifier have a value for column B, some have value for column C.

So, I want to group by the unique identifier and then get the non-null values for each column.

So, this is a grouping and then aggregating task. But unlike count or things like that, I am really creating a new row.

I am not finding a way to do so in pandas. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Example:>

```
    A   B        C       D
    1   null    null    100
    1   90      null    null
    2   null    1000    999
    1            80 
    2   1000    null    799

 df.groupby('A').first()
      B     C    D
A
1  null  null  100
2  null  1000  999
```

But the required output is:

```
     B     C    D
A
1  90     80  100
2  1000  1000  999
```

Comment: Something like  `df.groupby('A').first()`? This might be a duplicate.

Comment: what is the final data, that you are expecting ?

Comment: Can you confirm what it is you're looking for?

Comment: @coldspeed i added the sample output : just the non null values from each row with the same id

Comment: @jezrael its not a duplicate... how can it be the same? the questions ask two different things..i ahve updated the question with a sample output for clairty

Comment: @davidnadal - Do you think `df.replace('null', np.nan).groupby('A').first()` ?

Comment: @jezrael no..i dont want to replace null by np nan..its more like a merge between the rows with the same id after the groupby ..i want to extract all the non null values for each column after grouping them with the same id ... and then construct a single row for each group..

Comment: OK, is possible more `non-nans` values like in last column `12, null, 15` ?

Comment: @jezrael, its possible..then i just want to take the first one I guess..although I am sure that scenario will be quite rare in the data I have....anyways, i was worried about that condition and selecting the first value there will work..

Comment: @davidnadal - But `df.groupby('A').first()` does not work? Why? I test it and working nice.

Comment: @jezrael http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html Groupby first just takes the first row of "all the group rows" with the same id, right? It doesn't take first non-null values for each column.. Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486417/pandas-how-do-i-select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/30492281?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @davidnadal - hmmm, but it working as you need - it return first non nan. Try test it in small dataframe

Comment: @jezrael okay, let me test on the dataset..thanks!

Comment: @jezrael no..it doesnt work..i tested on a csv

Comment: `null` are `NaN`s ?

Comment: @jezrael i have given an example too

Comment: So need `df.replace('null', np.nan).groupby('A').first()`

Comment: @jezrael it works on this example!! could you explain as answer maybe, why is this happening, what does np.nan replacmenet have to do with this?

Comment: because `first` get first non nan values per grouops

Comment: Nobody answered @davidnadal. 

Hi David, if you are still wondering how to solve your problem: here is the answer (i've tested it):

`df = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill())`
`df.groupby('A').last()`