# Dataframe - Find first 0 in row grouped by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple data points for every day. I need to detect the first 0 of every day. I want to transform **Data** to the **Output** column.

[image: ho]

Data in reproducible format:

```
Date,Data,Output
1/1/2019,1,False
1/1/2019,1,False
1/1/2019,0,True
1/1/2019,0,False
1/1/2019,1,False
2/1/2019,1,False
2/1/2019,0,True
2/1/2019,1,False
3/1/2019,0,True
3/1/2019,0,False
```

I thought this might involve the groupby feature, but struggling to figure out how to start.

Comment: can you add pandas code to generate the frame, so we can try it on our end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas: how do I select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486417/pandas-how-do-i-select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: @Tserenjamts nahh. That's different.

Comment: btw, your title asks for last 0 but the content is first 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `duplicated`:

```
df["output"] = ~(df[df["Data"]==0].duplicated(subset=["Date","Data"],keep="first"))
df["output"].fillna(False, inplace=True)

print (df)

#
        Date  Data  output
0  1/01/2019     1   False
1  1/01/2019     1   False
2  1/01/2019     0    True
3  1/01/2019     0   False
4  1/01/2019     1   False
5  2/01/2019     1   False
6  2/01/2019     0    True
7  2/01/2019     1   False
8  3/01/2019     0    True
9  3/01/2019     0   False
```

Comment: Am I missing something. This output and the user input is the same. You event put the dates wrong

Comment: @YusufBaktir from OP: `I want to transform Data to the Output column`.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. Cool solution!

Comment: One question - what does the ~ do?

Comment: It inverts the boolean array.

Answer (score 0):

Try 2 boolean masks

```
m = df.Data.eq(0)
m1 = m.groupby(df.Date).cumsum().eq(1)    
df['New'] = m & m1

Out[834]:
        Date  Data    New
0  1/01/2019     1  False
1  1/01/2019     1  False
2  1/01/2019     0   True
3  1/01/2019     0  False
4  1/01/2019     1  False
5  2/01/2019     1  False
6  2/01/2019     0   True
7  2/01/2019     1  False
8  3/01/2019     0   True
9  3/01/2019     0  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Another groupby solution with loc

```
df.loc[df[df.data.eq(0)].groupby('date').data.idxmin(), 'out'] = True
df = df.fillna(False)
```